# Две формы на одной странице yii2

Tags: php, yii, form

Как сделать две разные формы на одной странице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и написали в комментарии просто вставляй две формы. Далее в контроллере лови через Post в данных "button1" или "button2".

```
<?php
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\bootstrap\Html;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form1']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'city_name')->textInput(); ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('button1', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'button1']); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form2']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'city_name')->textInput() ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('button2', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'button2']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: ДА СПАСИБО ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ)